# Memory leak and crash with delete[]

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, crash

I have a program that has a memory leak and every time I add delete to my code it crashes. I am just wondering if anyone has any idea why this is happening. The  code that crashes is below.
Here is the desturctor with the delete
the first and last name are declared as follows.

```
char* firstName;
char* lastName;


Name::~Name(){

    delete[] firstName;
    delete[] lastName;
}
```

and here is where the memory is allocated

```
Name::Name(Name& name){
    //copys the first and last name from one Name to the other

    firstName = new char [strlen(name.firstName)+1];
    strcpy(firstName,name.firstName);

    lastName = new char [strlen(name.lastName)+1];
    strcpy(lastName,name.lastName);

}
```

Comment: You're probably not following the rule of three. Use `std::string`.

Comment: would you please add the class part with the element's declaration?

Comment: firstName, lastName should be ended with '\0' symbol based on which strlen asses length is it so in your code? check this, as this might be the reason of your error

Comment: The problem could very well be the operator= or the constructor. If you didn't delete the operator= or built a custom one it is possible for two object to share the same strings and cause this.
working with std::strings or with unique_ptr really does simplify things

Comment: Are the declarations really outside your class definitioin?

Comment: No they are in a .h file

Comment: Please paste complete code and compile it, before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are assigning an object of your `Name` type at some point and there is no copy assignment (first I thought there is no copy constructor but you actually show your copy constructor). The default generated copy assignment just does a bitwise copy. As a result, you see a double `delete[]` of your pointers at some point (there is also a memory leak but this isn't as visible). Alternatively, how do your other constructors look like? Do have a default constructor possibly not initializing the pointers or a constructor which may end up storing pointers to string literals?

The best approach is **not** to use manual memory allocation but rather to use `std::string`. If you can't use `std::string`, e.g., because this is an assignment, I strongly recommend that you implement your own simple string class: dealing with multiple allocated entities without wrapping each individually into a suitable resource maintaining class is extremely hard. I can't do it correctly. Admittedly, I'm only programming in C++ since about 20 years.

For example, your copy constructor is not exception safe: if your second allocation throws an exception because there isn't enough memory to allocate, you have a resource leak. There are ways to deal with function-level try/catch blocks but it is much easier to use a string class: any fully constructed subobject is automatically destroyed if a constructor throws an exception. This way, the string's constructor takes care of the memory.

Comment: Thank you so much !, I found my error thanks to your answer. I owe you one :).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `firstName` and `lastName` are proper elements of your `Name` class, you should take care that [strlen doesn't check against NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5796140/2932052) and so you should deal either with NULLs

```
Name::Name(const Name& name){
    if (name.firstName) {
        int len_z = strlen(name.firstName)+1;
        firstName = new char [len_z];
        strncpy(firstName, name.firstName, len_z);
        // ^^^ also copy the terminator char ^^^
    } else {
        firstName = NULL;
    }
    // repeat for lastName:
    if (name.lastName) {
        int len_z = strlen(name.lastName)+1;
        lastName = new char [len_z];
        strncpy(lastName, name.lastName, len_z);

    } else {
        lastName = NULL;
    }
}
```

or create standard `Name` objects with a constructor like this:

```
Name::Name() {
    firstName = new char[1];
    firstName[0] = '\0';
    // repeat for lastName:
    lastName = new char[1];
    lastName[0] = '\0';
}
```

and at least here you see, why `std::string` is a much better choice: it's a class that implements all the aspects of strings you need. If you make this by hand, you have to double all of it for firstName and lastName ... and imagine there will a be soon a `middleName` in the next version of your `Name` class ...