# segmentation fault while calling strlen with a previously allocated pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char, segmentation-fault, strlen

Up until now I have had some code that worked perfectly regarding a variable called `wfiles`. wfiles is initialized within my main file:

```
char* wfiles = "";
```

Which as far as I can tell C has no complaints. Next the `wfiles` variable is allocated in a switch statement:

```
 switch (c) {
    case 't':
        /* the user wants a template */
        template = optarg;
        break;
    case 'f':
        wfiles = optarg;
        break;
    case 'v':
        vcs = optarg;
        break;
    case 'u':
        url = optarg;
        break;
    case 's':
        /* custom save location */
        save_loc = optarg;
        break;
    case '?':
        break;
    default:
        abort();
    }
```

finally I check for whether or not `wfiles` is empty:

```
if (!empty(wfiles))
```

empty is a macro that expands to `(strlen(wfiles) == 0)`

I cannot see any problems with this but when I run this code I get a segmentation fault. This had never happened before. When I ran the code in gdb with and without debugging symbols, I get one line pointed to the if statement earlier mentioned. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. The code you've shown seems to have no problems.

Comment: Where do you get `optarg` from? Since the only assignment to `wfiles` is from `optarg`, it is very likely that the memory it pointed to when it was assigned is not valid anymore when you are calling `strlen` later

Comment: @intricatedetail Simply output the string and its address and all will be clear.:)

Comment: optarg is from getopt.h and I cannot output the string, it immediately segfaults regardless

Comment: However commenting out the option parsing while loop solves the problem... I suspect I may have parsed the options wrong

Comment: `char* wfiles = "";` is poor style; string literals are not modifiable. `const char *wfiles = "";` should be used instead. The original version is grandfathered in from pre-ANSI C.

Comment: "Next the wfiles variable is allocated" - actually it is *assigned* here. You make the already-existing pointer `wfiles` point to a different location . No memory is allocated by `wfiles = optarg;`;  `optarg` must already exist. Another potential problem might be if the memory pointed to by `optarg` is released but you then still try to use `wfiles`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen()` will dereference a pointer, which may cause some problems when this pointer,i.e `optarg`, is not valid.

For example, in case of `optarg=NULL` and `c='f'`, your code will be executed as:

```
case 'f':
    wfiles = optarg;
    //Now wfiles=NULL
```

`strlen(wfiles)` will be: `strlen(NULL)` and segmentation fault happens.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796103/strlen-not-checking-for-null) for more reference

Comment: Thanks I never knew about this, I tweaked my macro and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

As mentioned in the other answers, truly you need to check for NULL before passing a pointer to `strlen()` . In your case, `optarg` may very well contain NULL. So, better put a NULL check against the incoming pointer in `empty()` MACRO.

<sup>However, the below point is still valid, so keeping it as it is.</sup>

---

I think, your issue maybe with the way you *assign* `optarg` to `wfiles`. `optarg` may change on different iterations. So, only *pointing* to `optarg` may give you faultly result. You need to *copy* the content of `optarg` for that particular iteration.

Instead of assigning (storing) the pointer, try

- allocating memory to `wfiles`.
- [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) the `optarg` to `wfiles`.

Or, you can make use of [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) directly.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to secure the macro `empty` by 1<sup>st</sup> testing whether its argument points to `NULL` before calling `strlen()`.

```
#define empty(s) (s) ?(0 == strlen(s)) :1
```

Comment: Or safer, faster & more readable: `inline bool is_empty (const char* str) { if(str == NULL){ return true; } return *str == '\0'; }`. But of course if the rest of the program was bug-free, the pointer would never be NULL anyhow.