# cant get return 0 , even if string is null

Tags: c, string, null

**Hi , i have problem with return value , program returning 1 even if str , text or both are null**

```
int prefix  ( char *str , char *text  ) {

    int len = strlen (text);
    if (str == NULL)
            return 0;

    else if (text == NULL )
            return 0;
    else {
            for (int i=0 ; i<=len-1 ; i++) {
                if (text[i]==str[i])
                    printf (" %d char equal \n",i);
                 else return 0;
         }

         return 1 ;

     }
}


int main () {

    int result = prefix ("","");

    printf ("%d\n",result);
}
```

Comment: `for (int i=0 ; i<=len-1 ; i++)` is the same as `for (int i=0 ; i<len ; i++)` and the second format is **MUCH** more usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the string "" is different from the string NULL. "" is a char* with a single '\0' character, and NULL is nothing.

Your problem here is that when you pass empty strings, the two checks are passed, and then for loop never executes because the strings don't have any characters (0 <= -1 is false). Therefore there is never a chance to return 0, and thus the return 1 is always called.

Answer (score 1):

`""` is not `NULL` it is the empty string.  Also you should have to check for `NULL` before `strlen` as [`strlen` does not check for `NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796103/strlen-not-checking-for-null).