# Segmentation fault at the end of a *char array

Tags: c, arrays, linux, segmentation-fault, memory-segmentation

I'm new to using C and I'm running into a problem. I want to use the following code to split-up a string input from the linux command line (something like `date | ./date_split`) into an array, which I will be later accessing and modifying. The splitting works initially but I get a segmentation fault at the end. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
   char *indate[10];
   int i= 1;
   char str[100][50];
   fgets(&str [0], 50, stdin);
   const char s[2] = " ";
   char *token;

  /* get the first token */
  token = strtok(str, s);
  indate[i] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
  strcpy(indate[i], token);
  printf( "Array before: %s\n", indate[i]);     

 /* walk through other tokens */
 while( token != NULL )
{
  printf( "Token before: %s\n", token );

  token = strtok(NULL, s);
  indate[i] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
  strcpy(indate[i], token);

printf( "Token2 After: %s\n", token );
printf( "Array2 After: %s\n", indate[i]);     
i++;   
}

    return(0);
}
```

Which gives terminal output:

```
Array before: Thu
Token before: Thu
Token2 After: 20
Array2 After: 20
Token before: 20
Token2 After: Oct
Array2 After: Oct
Token before: Oct
Token2 After: 11:37:56
Array2 After: 11:37:56
Token before: 11:37:56
Token2 After: EDT
Array2 After: EDT
Token before: EDT
Token2 After: 2016

Array2 After: 2016

Token before: 2016

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `fgets(&str[0], 50, stdin);` looks wrong to me. You're passing a `char **` value instead of `char *`. Did you compile this code with warnings enabled? Try adding `-Wall` to the command line options. **Edit:** `token = strtok(str, s);` is also wrong; `str` should be `char *`, not `char **`. This would be a good time to start learning how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger).

Comment: It does indeed give me warnings at fgets as you said, and I had no idea a debugger existed thanks for letting me know! I've figured it out how to get it to run without a segmentation fault, when I add an `if (token==Null) {break;}` before updating the array. But I still don't know why that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues with your program: your index into the date components, `i`, starts at 1 instead of 0 (is a terrible variable name for this purpose) and isn't updated consistently (first entry gets overwritten); the `str()` array is a total mess allocation-wise (e.g. two dimensions, only one used); you assume the first `strtok()` succeeds but that might not be the case with bad input; you don't test if the subsequent `strtok()` calls succeed until after you've already used the result; you make no attempt to `free()` the memory you `malloc()` and even lose track of some.

Below is a rework of your original code that also adds some error checking and other niceties:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXIMUM_TOKENS 16
#define MAXIMUM_TOKEN_LENGTH 32

const char *separator = " ";

int main()
{
    char string[(MAXIMUM_TOKEN_LENGTH + strlen(separator)) * MAXIMUM_TOKENS + 1]; // estimate

    char *result = fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

    if (result == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "An appropriate error message goes here.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* strip final newline (\n) if present */
    size_t last_index = strlen(string) - 1;

    if (string[last_index] == '\n')
    {
        string[last_index] = '\0';
    }

    /* get the first token */
    char *token = strtok(string, separator);

    char *date_parts[MAXIMUM_TOKENS];
    int date_parts_index = 0;

    /* walk through other tokens */
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        date_parts[date_parts_index++] = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, separator);
    }

    /* print the tokens and free the strdup/malloc memory */
    for (int i = 0; i < date_parts_index; i++)
    {
        (void) puts(date_parts[i]);
        free(date_parts[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
% date | ./a.out
Thu
Oct
20
09:58:00
PDT
2016
%
```

Although this is an appropriate use of `strtok()`, be wary of it.  It is an artifact of an earlier age and should be avoided in favor of safer, modern library functions like `strsep()` and `strtok_r()`.

Comment: Wow, that is infinitely better than what I had written, thank you so much! I'll take your suggestions to heart and modify what I had written accordingly

Answer (score 1):

From strtok() manual

> RETURN VALUE
>          The  strtok()  and  strtok_r()  functions  return a pointer to the next
>          token, or NULL if there are no more tokens.

Once there are no more tokens, `token` contains a NULL pointer, and therefore `strlen(token)` seg faults. See [strlen not checking for NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796103/strlen-not-checking-for-null)